# changes in log4j.properties file of ksql (confluent)

Tags: log4j, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I have followed the steps mentioned [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/installation/installing.html) and installed confluent ksql.

I observed log messages on my console after starting ksql server using `/bin/ksql-server-start /etc/ksql/ksql-server.properties`

I'm new to logj logging framework.
I want to redirect ksql console messages to a log file instead of stdout.
There are four log files related to ksql. The are present here - https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/tree/master/config.

I think [log4j-rolling.properties](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/blob/master/config/log4j-rolling.properties) is responsible for ksql server logging.

I got to know that we need file appender for this, but I did not find file appender in any of the log4j files

what are the changes that I have to make in log4j file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what version of ksql you're using, but looking at the latest released version of ksqlDB, i.e. 0.9, the [log4j-rolling.properties](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/blob/0.9.x-ksqldb/config/log4j-rolling.properties) file, (which the command you're running will use by default), defines file appenders, for example:

```
log4j.appender.main=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
```

If you're seeing a different result, maybe consider upgrading to a later version of ksqlDB, or copying the log4j and startup scripts from the 0.9 release and using them with your version may work.